# Получить родителя TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется структура `TreeView`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="subItems">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
          //...
      </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="items"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding }" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource subItems}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          //...
      </StackPanel>                
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="root"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource items}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>  


<TreeView x:Name="myTreeView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource root}"
                              SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding }">   
</TreeView>
```

Я могу получить нужный мне выделенный элемент в дереве таким способом:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    ItemClass item = e.NewValue as ItemClass;
    if (item != null)
    {
        SelectedItem = item;  //SelectedItem - DependencyProperty
    } 
}
```

Вопрос в том, как получить первого родителя вверх по дереву который содержит выделенный TreeViewItem?

Comment: А зачем вам? Раз вы пользуетесь MVVM, это должно быть ненужно.

Comment: @VladD, для сохранения текущего состояния дерева(сохранить имя выбранного элемента и имя его родителя) при закрытии программы. Затем при открытии программы всю картину восстановить. Я конечно могу сохранить сам объект, но получается слишком большой xml-файл, а так, я его найду этот элемент в коллекции и выделю его.

Comment: да и в случае сохранения объекта, мне все равно нужно знать имя его родителя, потому что не понятно какой именно элемент выбирать.

Comment: Сохранения состояния должны быть на уровне модели, а не презентации. Вы поставили себе неправильную задачу.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void TreeViewItem_OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        ItemsControl parent = GetSelectedTreeViewItemParent(item);

        TreeViewItem treeitem = parent as TreeViewItem;
        string MyValue= treeitem .Header.ToString();//Gets you the immediate parent
    }
}
public ItemsControl GetSelectedTreeViewItemParent(TreeViewItem item)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    while (!(parent is TreeViewItem || parent is TreeView))
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    return parent as ItemsControl;
}
```

Взято из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005119/get-the-parent-node-of-a-child-in-wpf-c-sharp-treeview) поста

Comment: Увы, такой метод я пробовал, он не подходит для такой структуры.